# Algorithm to generate single iterative formula from an arbitrary sequence of numbers.

Tags: reference-request, algorithms

The end goal is to be able to compress paragraphs of words into arbitrary formulae, where the formula is calculated by some software using algorithms.

So, is it possible to generate arbitrary sequences of numbers from a single iterative formula? for example, if I give you a sequence of numbers {14, 49, 19}, could you give me an iterative formula that computes the entire sequence of numbers?

From https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295737/is-it-possible-to-find-a-formula-for-a-set-of-number-from-the-result, my guess is that there exists infinite iterative formulas. As a side note, I want to know what mathematical topics are related to my question.

Comment: I hope you don't expect to get compression from this process!

Comment: I searched data compression and found a range of good resources. You might also be interested in Kolmogorov Complexity - but be aware that you are asking a question which has had huge amounts of attention (storing digital images, transmitting messages, archiving data etc) and generated some heavy duty theory. Go for the easy sources first and see if they do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [Interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation).

A possible solution (which may not appear to be *iterative*, but quite *direct*) is the [Polynomial interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation) which can construct a polynomial which, when given indices $1,\cdots,n$ as the $x$-value, results in your numbers $a[1],\cdots,a[n]$.

This polynomial is unique if the degree is limited to $n-1$, e.g. there's only one straight line (polynomial of degree one) which passes through two given points $(1,a[1])$ and $(2,a[2])$ on the plane. But there are infinitely many such polynomials if the degree is not limited (just add a point $(n+1, t)$, with random $t$).

Note this gives a "wrong" solution to almost all *newspaper problems*, since the numbers are mostly not constructed using polynomials. But this is my favorite solution, as a nerd, demonstrating there are infinitely many solutions to such problems(given only a finite sequence).